# Images in UITableViewCell change after scrolling down and back up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a picture and some labels inside my cells. If I have more cells than what can fit on the page, scrolling down then back up loads a different image momentarily then loads the original photo. I have read around StackOverflow to see what would work in my case, but so far I can't find anything since my UITableView is inside a ViewController.

Here is how I load my content into my cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
    let post = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
    cell.titleLabel.text = post["title"] as? String
    cell.priceLabel.text = post["price"] as? String
    if let imageName = post["image"] as? String {
        let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/\(imageName)")
        imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in if error == nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                cell.titleLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.postImageView.alpha = 1
                cell.priceLabel.alpha = 1
            cell.postImageView.image = image
            })
        } else {
            print("Error occured during image download: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
    }
    return cell
}
```

Is there any way I could change `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` to something different so this doesn't happen?

Comment: try set image in method with `willDisplayCell `

Comment: Why are you animating your image? Just set it before the animation.

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski Should I set the whole function to use willDisplayCell?

Comment: @gabe create cell in function with `cellForRowAt` but set variable like as `titleLabel.text`, `titleLabel.color` set in function with `willDisplayCell`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your table view cell PostTableViewCell you need to implement the method

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.postImageView.image = nil
    // Set cell to initial state here, reset or set values
}
```

The cells are holding on to their old content

Comment: This does work, but I worry about users with a slow/metered Internet connection having to load the image every time they scroll. Is there any way  I could cache the image?

Comment: to do that you would need to separate the loading the images off the server code from the loading images into a table cell code but I am not familiar enough with fire base to know exactly how to do that.  They must have an in-app memory store u can utilize

Comment: Apple documentation says about prepareForReuse: "For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. " But my UITableView has not to many cells so this solution works for me perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you run into problems because you update the cell inside the completion block. If the cell scrolls out of view before the completion block is run, it'll be reused for a different row, but you're still setting the image for the previous row.

Try this:

```
imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in if error == nil {
        if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? PostTableViewCell {
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                cell.titleLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.postImageView.alpha = 1
                cell.priceLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.postImageView.image = image
            }
        })
```

Instead of relying on the cell still being visible, this will try to get it from the table view based on `indexPath`. If it's not visible any more, `cellForRow(at:)` will return `nil`.